# How to point /product-category/ and /product-tag/ to a custom URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce, permalinks

I'm using WooCommerce products to list `lessons`. My product categories currently have 3 product (lesson) categories:

Level 1;
Level 2;
Level 3

Instead of having the old ugly product category archive page, I've created custom pages for the /product-category/ and /product-tag/ archives.

So my new category page for Level 1 where all products from this category are displayed is `example.com/lessons/online/level-1` ( where `lessons` is a page, `online` is a page and `level-1` is also a page )

Now the problem is that when I visit the single product page of one of my lessons, in the summary just above the add to cart button, it has a link to `product-category` archives of the Level 1 category.

So this link points to `example.com/product-category/level-1`

Is it possible to change this URL, so it points to my newly created category page at `example.com/lessons/online/level-1` instead?

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by using permalink structure for change product category url you have to follow steps : 
    1: Login as admin.
    2: Go to setting ->parmalink.
    3: Here you find Product category base and Product tag base.
    4: Put here what you want in your case add lessons/online.
    5: Make save changes.
    
    Now check may be your problem will solve.